# One-Max fitness function (Java)

Tags: algorithms, java, genetic-algorithms

Whilst searching on Google about Genetic Algorithms, I came across OneMax Problem, my search showed that this is one of the very first problem that the Genetic Algorithm was applied to. However, I am not exactly sure what is OneMax problem and how can the One-Max problem be represented as a fitness function in java using the following formula which I came across during my search? Can anyone help me out?

S is = to N length of binary string

$
\begin{align*}
OneMax(S) = \sum_{i=1}^ns_i
\end{align*}
$

Any help is appreciated

Comment: As you've said, the problem is simply to maximize the sum of ones in a bitstring. The fitness you'd like to maximize *is* that sum. Is there something else that's unclear?

Answer (score 0):

With the OneMax problem you are searching for a bitstring where all values are filled with ones.

The fitness can be caluculated by summing all the values of the binary string

```
int calcFitness(Bit[] bitstring){
    int fitness = 0;
    for( int i = 0; 1 < bitstring.length; ++i)
    {
         fitness += bittring[i];
    }
    return fitness;
}
```

You should replace Bit[] by something that actually exist, like int[] (where you would habe to make sure that only 0s and 1es are created or by using an own class...